# How to extract few tabs from a xml file using zgrep or sed

Tags: linux, xml, zgrep

I have a big size file like 5GB with `.gz`. Inside that file, we have few XML files that contains values that I want to search and extract just in case if those values are there.

For example I want to extract the tags that contains the name `NOOSS` and also the subcontent of this tags like  `<pmJobId>`, `<requestedJobState>`,  `<reportingPeriod>`, `<jobPriority>` from the the `.gz` file

```xml
<Pm xmlns="urnCmwPm">
    <pmId>1</pmId>
    <PmJob>
        <pmJobId>NOOSSCONTROLExample</pmJobId>
        <requestedJobState>ACTIVE</requestedJobState>
        <reportingPeriod>FIVE_MIN</reportingPeriod>
        <jobType>MEASUREMENTJOB</jobType>
        <jobPriority>HIGH</jobPriority>
        <granularityPeriod>FIVE_MIN</granularityPeriod>
        <jobGroup>Sla</jobGroup>
        <reportContentGeneration>CHANGED_ONLY</reportContentGeneration>
        <MeasurementReader>
            <measurementReaderId>mr_2</measurementReaderId>
            <measurementSpecification struct="MeasurementSpecification">
                <measurementTypeRef>Anything</measurementTypeRef>
            </measurementSpecification>
            <thresholdRateOfVariation>PER_SECOND</thresholdRateOfVariation>
        </MeasurementReader>
        <MeasurementReader>
            <measurementReaderId>mr_1</measurementReaderId>
            <measurementSpecification struct="MeasurementSpecification">
                <measurementTypeRef>ManagedElement=1,SystemFunctions=1,Pm=1,PmGroup=OSProcessingLogicalUnit,MeasurementType=CPULoad.Total</measurementTypeRef>
            </measurementSpecification>
            <thresholdRateOfVariation>PER_SECOND</thresholdRateOfVariation>
        </MeasurementReader>
    </PmJob>
</Pm>
```

I was using `cat *gz 1 zgrep -a "PmJobId"` but the output only show the `<pmJobId>` value and not the rest of the information or tags.

Please your help, I'm noobie on this.

Im using CentOS - RedHat Linux.

Thanks

Comment: A single compressed file can't contain multiple other files unless it's an archive of some sort. Do I understand you correctly that you want the `PmJob` node and all its sub-nodes if the corresponding `pmJobId` node's value contains the substring `NOOSS`? And you want the actual XML?  It would benefit if you could show the result, given the example document you include in the question.

Comment: The namespace declaration, i.e `xmlns="urnCmwPm"` contains an invalid URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the XML document in `file.xml` is well-formed and correct in all ways (the example in the question has a faulty namespace declaration), then you would be able to extract the part of the document that corresponds to the `PmJob` nodes that have a `pmJobID` value that contains the substring `NOOSS` with the command-line XML parser `xmlstarlet`.

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//PmJob[contains(pmJobId,"NOOSS")]' -nl file.xml
```

This command selects all `PmJob` nodes with a child node, `pmJobId`, whose value contains the substring `NOOSS`. The utility will return a copy of the selected `PmJob` node and all its child nodes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, is there any way or another similar command? This command xmlstarlet is not supported in RedHat. Thank you.

Comment: @JuanPabloBustamanteLuna I think you will find [that it is supported](https://snapcraft.io/install/xmlstarlet/rhel).

Comment: Thank you for share this. Unfortunately, the server is not able to install additional packages since the server is under production and for security reasons is not connected to the internet to get and install packages.

Comment: I'm going to try in my local VM with RHEL. I will keep you posted about this possible resolution. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the XML document is well-formed and valid, you can use the `xmllint` utility to output the requisite nodes.

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//PmJob[contains(pmJobId,"NOOSS")]' file.xml
<PmJob>
        <pmJobId>NOOSSCONTROLExample</pmJobId>
        <requestedJobState>ACTIVE</requestedJobState>
        <reportingPeriod>FIVE_MIN</reportingPeriod>
        <jobType>MEASUREMENTJOB</jobType>
        <jobPriority>HIGH</jobPriority>
        <granularityPeriod>FIVE_MIN</granularityPeriod>
        <jobGroup>Sla</jobGroup>
        <reportContentGeneration>CHANGED_ONLY</reportContentGeneration>
        <MeasurementReader>
            <measurementReaderId>mr_2</measurementReaderId>
            <measurementSpecification struct="MeasurementSpecification">
                <measurementTypeRef>Anything</measurementTypeRef>
            </measurementSpecification>
            <thresholdRateOfVariation>PER_SECOND</thresholdRateOfVariation>
        </MeasurementReader>
        <MeasurementReader>
            <measurementReaderId>mr_1</measurementReaderId>
            <measurementSpecification struct="MeasurementSpecification">
                <measurementTypeRef>ManagedElement=1,SystemFunctions=1,Pm=1,PmGroup=OSProcessingLogicalUnit,MeasurementType=CPULoad.Total</measurementTypeRef>
            </measurementSpecification>
            <thresholdRateOfVariation>PER_SECOND</thresholdRateOfVariation>
        </MeasurementReader>
    </PmJob>
$
```

This utility is installed by default on many Linux distributions.